# Parameterized replacements in log4j needs empty string?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, slf4j

```
./spark-shell

scala> import org.slf4j.{Logger, LoggerFactory}
import org.slf4j.{Logger, LoggerFactory}

scala> val LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger("testing")
LOGGER: org.slf4j.Logger = org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter(testing)

scala> val v1 = "1"
v1: String = 1

scala> val v2 = "2"
v2: String = 2
```

This doesn't work as I expected:

```
scala> LOGGER.warn("something {}, something {}", v1, v2)
<console>:30: error: ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
both method warn in trait Logger of type (x$1: String, x$2: Any, x$3: Any)Unit
and  method warn in trait Logger of type (x$1: String, x$2: Object*)Unit
match argument types (String,String,String)
       LOGGER.warn("something {}, something {}", v1, v2)
              ^
```

However this does:

```
scala> LOGGER.warn("something {}, something {}", v1, v2, "")
16/05/30 10:16:59 WARN testing: something 1, something 2
```

Is there something wrong I'm doing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually doesn't need an empty string, but at least 3 arguments or a type cast. Indeed, there are two overloaded methods matching the firm, which are the two shown there. Thus, if you need to put any number of items but 2, everything will work as you expect. In this particular case, with two objects, you can do one of the following:

1. Inserting a third argument, so that the second firm (`(x$1: String, x$2: Object*)Unit`) is matched, like you have said (the third argument will be ignored).
2. Cast the two arguments to `Any`, in this way the first firm will be matched (by typing `LOGGER.warn("something {}, something {}", v1:Any, v2:Any)`)